# How can I get one slide to reference the number of another in powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I would like to have a textbox in one of my powerpoint slides say "see slide [x]" where x is another slide.  Is there any way to do this cleanly so that it updates dynamically as I move the slides around the deck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, other than by writing/running code to clean up the references whenever you've moved slides around.